# How to know the aluminium sulfate solubility as function of the pH?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, solubility, ph

I'm trying to find a diagram or a reference for to know the solubility of aluminium sulfate $\mathrm{Al_{2}(SO_{4})_{3}}$ in differents pH values. Something like:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If the question only is about the diagram and the reference:

[image]

> Rubin, A. J., & Hayden, P. L. (1973). Studies on the Hydrolysis and Precipitation of Aluminum (III). page 57.

But the interpretation is not clear for me, so [here](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/86432/55473) is a new question