# Aluminium sulphate solubility as function of the pH

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, solubility, ph, precipitation

earlier I asked about how to know the aluminium sulfate solubility as function of the ph ([see the previous question here](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/86424/55473)). I found this diagram on the page 57 of

> Rubin, A. J., & Hayden, P. L. (1973). Studies on the Hydrolysis and
>   Precipitation of Aluminum (III).

[image]

But I'm a little confused about the interpretation. Is the
$\mathrm{Al_{2}(SO_{4})_{3}}$ insoluble between pH 5 and 7?. What will be the correct interpretation of this diagram?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The lack of continuity for the curve indicates that the concentration of $\ce{Al2(SO4)3}$ was below the detection limit of the analytical technique being used to measure the concentration of $\ce{Al2(SO4)3}$ in the solution.

Theoretically there should be a continuous curve.

+1 for asking this as a new question.

Answer (score 1):

Solutions of aluminum sulfate are highly acidic. The Merck Index states that at a concentration $0.2 M$, the pH is $3.0$.